# Window Size for RemoteWebDriver Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I'm trying to change window size for selenium RemoteWebDriver. 
I execute:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

but it doesn't work when working with RemoteWebDriver and CHROME.

Does anybody know how to solve that?

Comment: i've never had a problem with doing that.  are you positive it's not?

Comment: Of course it's working, time to have a rest, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
this.driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

Comment: This problem occur, because you use RemoteWebDriver not WebDriver.